# Is there a different between @Html.RenderPartialAsync and reload the partialview with ajax in JS?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-ajax, partial-views

All I want to know is, if is there a different between these two commands.
Do they different calls to the server and is there a different in performance or is RenderPartialAsync just a short form for the ajax call?

in View

```
 @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_Tilemanager");}
```

in JS

```
$("#div1").load("_TileManager");
```

Answer (score 0):

They are not the same, `Html.RenderPartialAsync` runs on server side, so, all your html will be returned in one call, while jQuery `load()` method will load data from the server and place the returned HTML into the matched elements, so there will be a separate call to the server: http://api.jquery.com/load/

I'm not even sure that your `$("#div1").load("_TileManager");` call will work, because the `load()` method expects a URL as a parameter.

It is hard to talk about the performance without measuring, but probably when you're using jQuery the page will load faster, but after that it will make an extra call to the server to get the missing peace, so the page will load faster, but loading the missing part separately is probably slower overall then loading everything at once.